# Maximum limit for using ordinal units in month for DateTime in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, datetime

I was reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

and I am not sure if `twelfth` is the maximum for ordinal values.

The reason is I want to do something like

`$startDate = new \DateTime('twenty-third day of this month');`

and I am not sure what's the maximum limit for the ordinal value for the day part of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [php 7.0.4 `twelfth` is the "largest"](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.4/ext/date/lib/parse_date.c#L239) ordinal supported:

```
/* The relative text table. */
static timelib_lookup_table const timelib_reltext_lookup[] = {
    { "first",    0,  1 },
    { "next",     0,  1 },
    { "second",   0,  2 },
    { "third",    0,  3 },
    { "fourth",   0,  4 },
    { "fifth",    0,  5 },
    { "sixth",    0,  6 },
    { "seventh",  0,  7 },
    { "eight",    0,  8 },
    { "eighth",   0,  8 },
    { "ninth",    0,  9 },
    { "tenth",    0, 10 },
    { "eleventh", 0, 11 },
    { "twelfth",  0, 12 },
    { "last",     0, -1 },
    { "previous", 0, -1 },
    { "this",     1,  0 },
    { NULL,       1,  0 }
};
```